# bash extract ip from log file and save to ext text file

Tags: bash

I need to create a bash file to search all lines contained this in the log file

```
Aug  9 16:11:46 igs kernel: [ATTS] Caution: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx SRC=1.1.1.1 DST=192.168.0.100 LEN=33 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=121 ID=9690 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=601 DPT=12500 LEN=13
Aug  9 16:11:46 igs kernel: [ATTS] Caution: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx SRC=2.2.2.2 DST=192.168.0.100 LEN=33 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=121 ID=9689 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=602 DPT=12502 LEN=13
Aug  9 16:11:46 igs kernel: [ATTS] Caution: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx SRC=3.3.3.3 DST=192.168.0.100 LEN=33 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=121 ID=9691 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=600 DPT=12503 LEN=13
Aug  9 16:11:46 igs kernel: [ATTS] Caution: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx SRC=1.1.1.1 DST=192.168.0.100 LEN=33 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=121 ID=9691 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=600 DPT=12503 LEN=13
```

Then extract the IP in "SRC=" and save the IP to external file with name "ip.list" but not repeat the same IP

Example output for ip.list

```
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` also can do that:

```
 sed 's/.*SRC=\([0-9.]\+\).*/\1/' infile | sort -u
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `awk` and `sort` for this:

```
awk '/Caution: IN=/ {print substr($11,5)}' infile | sort -u
```

Just adjust the search string to be what you want (I've used `"Caution: IN="`).

What the `awk` does is, for every lime matching the search string, it prints out the eleventh argument (`"SRC=aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd"`) from the fifth character onwards (the first digit of the IP address).

The output of that is then passed through `sort -u` which first sorts then removes duplicate lines.

The output is what you would expect:

```
pax> awk '/Caution: IN=/ {print substr($11,5)}' infile | sort -u
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Or with `grep` and `coreutils`:

```
grep Caution: logfile | cut -d= -f5 | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort -u
```